# why the frame value changes for an NSWindow with setFrame

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow

Here is my playground

```
import Cocoa

class Pichico: NSWindow {
}

let f = Pichico()
print("will set frame")
let rect =  CGRect(x: CGFloat(1), y: CGFloat(2), width: CGFloat(3.456), height: CGFloat(7.890))

f.setFrame(rect, display: false)
print("did set frame" , f.frame)
```

**Result**:

```
will set frame

did set frame (1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0)
```

can anyone explain to me why the frame value has changed ?

Comment: NSWindow only accepts integers for the frame, so the CGFloats are automatically rounded when used.

Comment: thank you, I agree with you but it is not written in the documentation or I did not find

Comment: Note that even on a Retina display, where 1 point is backed by 2 pixels, you can't even use x.5 positions to get pixel-precise positioning or sizing.

Comment: thank you for this information